# Finding words that both itself and its reversal is in the file

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm, hash

Here is the scenario, you are trying to find all words in a large text file whose reversion is also in the file.

By "reversal", I mean that giving a word "abc", look to see if "cba" is in the file. And the text file contains about 10,000,000 words. The length of the words is no longer than 1000.

The idea that I came up with is finding a hash to map a word and its reversion to the same key. And sort respect to the key. So now you can check linearly to find all possible words eligible.

Question is: "**Find this hash**". And any other tricky solution to this problem is welcome.

If I can find a hash to map the strings to a key, I can use a external sorting to sort them and make the strings and their reversals adjacent. So it's trivial to find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple hash is: any hash (which provides a big enough hash space)!

Suppose your string is "foo". It's reverse is "oof". In some arbitrary order (e.g. lexicographical order), "foo" appears before "oof". Now hash the string appearing first in that order.

So instead of

```
hash = fancyHash(string);
```

you do

```
std::string rstring(string.rbegin(), string.rend());
hash = (string < rstring) ? anyhash(string) : anyhash(rstring);
```

---

A way using linux tools as @HighPerformanceMark suggested:
(text is a file containing your words. they may be on the same line, it doesn't matter)

```
rev text | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" | tr " " "\n" > rtext; rev rtext > rrtext; comm -12 <(sort -u rrtext) <(sort -u rtext);
```

Explanation:

`rev` reverses a file, therefore `rev text` outputs the reverse
`tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"` transforms everything to lower case (optional. don't do that if "Foo" doesn't count as reverse of "oOf")
`tr " " "\n"` gives every word a separate file

After this, the file `rtext` contains lower case (optional) words on distinct lines. Every word in this file is a reversed word of file `text`.

`rev rtext > rrtext` reverses one again to get the lower case stuff to the original too and also separating each word on different lines.

`comm -12 <(sort -u rrtext) <(sort -u rtext)`. As input to `comm`, we give the two text files which we sort first and duplicates (`-u`). Option `-12` supresses all words that are either unique to the first input (`rrtext`) or the second input (`rtext`). Therefore, every output of this command is present in both files.

Answer (score 2):

So, if you read all the words into a `map` (or `unordered_map`, which implements through a hash-table), then you can walk through the list of words, and find (using the `map.find(the_word.reverse())` - if that comes back with a valid word, you have the word in the list. Otherwise, there is no reverse variant of the word.

Comment: Good one for small file, but this will not work giving the condition that the file contains about 10,000,000 strings, too large for the hashmap to load into memory.

Comment: And if I can find a hash to map the strings to a key, I can use a external sorting to sort them and make the strings and their reversals adjacent. So it's trivial to find them.

Comment: Is that 10M "unique" words, or 10M words, some of which are unique? If so, how many are unique? And "max length = 1000", but what is the average? I would still follow the above route - 10M * average of 500 characters, say, is 5GB, so easily doable in a modern system.

Answer (score 2):

Read the input list.  For every word write two into an output list, the word itself and its reversal.  Sort the output list.  Words whose reversal appear in the original list will occur twice (in successive locations) in the sorted output list, words whose reversal is not in the original list will appear only once.

I think you could do this in one line using standard Linux file processing utilities and a few pipes. For example

```
rev wordlist.txt > revlist.txt && cat wordlist.txt revlist.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Given the speed of modern off-the-shelf sorting routines I suspect this might outperform more complex algorithms with lower (asymptotic) complexity.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: what if the file contains the same word twice but not the reverse form?

Comment: Then my simple approach would break :-(

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark well one has to modify your approach, but it remains simple imho. See my answer for a possible modification

Answer (score 2):

get sorted a list of all words (in a program or via gnu shell tools),
get a sorted list of all reversed words (same)
intersect the lists (aka join as gnu tool)

instead of lists, a program can, of course, also use set representations, especially hashsets (unordered_set). however, if the file are really large, you may run into memory problems, whereas sort & join can work disk-based. furthermore, hashsets are not really good for calculating the intersection

concerning your solution:
if the same word is contained twice, it will also have the same hash and appear to exist reversed

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that won't run into problems if "cat" and "cat" appear in the same file without "tac".

```
Create a HashSet to hold strings.

For each word w in the file

  Reverse w (call it revW)

  If HashSet contains revW

    Both w and revW appear in the file, add it to our results list.

  Regardless, Add w into the HashSet (we might see another revW later on)
```

Algorithmically, you read through the file just one time, you reverse every word once, you look in the hashset for the reverse of every word once, and you add every word into the hashset.

So this algorithm is linear complexity, assuming the HashSet/HashFunction offer constant time look-up/insert.

(Optionally keep a count with each word in the HashSet to keep track of how many times that word appears).

So, all words get hashed forwards, but you only look them up reversed.